# Debugger does not connect to Monodevelop (Simulator and real device)

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Mac OS X Lion, Xcode 4.1, Monotouch 4.0.6, Monodevelop 2.8 Alpha 2.
When trying to debug in the simulator, the debugger does not connect. The app starts without the debugger reacting. Monodevelop sits there and tells me it is waiting to connect to the debugger.

When trying to debug on the device, the iPhone vibrates once and the app won't start.

I tried:

- Disable firewall
- Downgrade to Monodevelop 2.4
- Create a new test project
- Reset the simulator
- Check the debug settings in the simulator
- Cleaned the solution and rebuilt
- Checked the the DEBUG build really is debug, that linker is disabled, LLVM is inactive

Everything is a fresh install. There is no Xcode 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug that occurs when using MonoDevelop 2.6RC1 and newer with MonoTouch 4.0.5 and newer. It's been fixed, and the fix will be released soon.

http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=424

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with some help from Xamarin support and some "unknown ingredients", but I'm not really satisfied with the solution.

First try was to change the debug settings on the simulator. The host IP was set to "automatic". I changed that to my real IP and it worked.
But this is new behavior, I never had to do it like this.

The trick did not work on the iPhone. So I installed Xcode 3 with SDK 4.3 and hooray now both, simulator and device work. However, I have no idea why.